# Find the longest repeating sequence

Tags: java, pattern-matching, byte

there is such a question. I have a method that reads the bytes from a file into an array, and the method that searches for the longest byte sequence in this array.

```
private int element;
private int lastElement;
private int length;

private byte[] readByteFromFile(File name) throws IOException {
            return Files.readAllBytes(name.toPath());
        }

private void searchByte(byte[] byteMass) {
    for (int i = 0; i < byteMass.length; i++) {
        int count = 0;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < byteMass.length; j++) {
            if (byteMass[i + count] == byteMass[j]) {
                if (count >= length) {
                    length = count + 1;
                    element = i;
                    lastElement = j - count;
                }
                count++;
            } else {
                count = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Suppose that my file contains such a sequence of numbers:

> 444478126354444

In the case of processing, my method will deduce that the first occurrence was at 0, and the second at 11 and length of sequence = 4

But if I have such a sequence

> 133333444478126354444

Then my method will deduce that the first occurrence was at 1, and the second at 2, and the length of the sequence 4

How it can be fixed, that the method to continue to work correctly?

Comment: can you be more specific what do you want from this string  `444478126354444` which digit occurs more no of times? or what?

Comment: You need to somehow keep track of the entire pattern. One way to do this is is to include the start and end index, and make sure your matches don't overlap. I'd encourage you to try to figure out how to do this and answer your own question.

Comment: I want to get the longest repeating sequence of bytes that are stored in an array of bytes. In this line the longest repeating sequence is 4, the length of the sequence is also 4, its first occurrence from 0 to 4, and the second from 11 to 15. But if before adding this sequence add 133333444478126354444, then my method counts sequence 3 as the longest and outputs its length is 4, the first occurrence is 1 - 5, the second is 2 - 6. I need that if there is such a line it continues the sequence of numbers 4 as the longest repeated one)

Comment: You should edit your question to clarify that your goal is to find the **longest** repeating sequence

Comment: Also, where are your declarations of `length`, `element` and `lastElement`?

Comment: added it into my post

Answer (score 0):

It is not tested. Don't have IDE infront of me.
The changes from the original code are. The second loop iterates one element less. If the next element is not equel to the previous then the loop exits.

```
private void searchByte(byte[] byteMass) {
        int maxLength = 0
        int element;
        for (int i = 0; i < byteMass.length; i++) {
            int count = 0;
            for (int j = i + 1; j < byteMass.length-1; j++) {
                if (byteMass[i] == byteMass[j]) {
                    if (count > length) {
                        maxLength = count;
                        element = i;
                    }
                    count++;
                } else {

                    break;
                 }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already I think it's ***very important*** to **trace out the logic of your code!!!** It's really important that you attempt to do this before asking for help. If you rely on  others to work out your own logic, you won't make much progress as a programmer.

That being said, let's dive in and follow your code when it runs with the problem input (this isn't actual code, we're just looking at the values as the program runs)

```
byteMass = 133333444478126354444
(byteMass.length = 21)
length = 0
    0 (i) < 21 (byteMass.length): true
        count = 0
        1 (j) < 21: true
            1 (byteMass[0 (i + count)]) == 3 (byteMass[1 (j)]): false
                count = 0
        2 (j) < 21: true
            1 (byteMass[0 (i + count)]) == 3 (byteMass[2 (j)]): false
                count = 0
        3 (j) < 21: true
            1 == 3: false
```

it continues on like this, but something interesting happens when j = 12

```
        12 (j) < 21: true
            1 (byteMass[0 (i + count)]) == 1 (byteMass[12 (j)]): true
                0 (count) >= 0 (length): true
                    length = 1 (count + 1)
                    element = 0 (i)
                    lastElement = 12 (j - count)
                count = 1
```

This, to me at least, looks like unexpected behavior! We want to count repeated numbers, but this 1 is 11 digits away from the previous 1! We can fix this by editing the inner for loop like this

```
for (int j = i + 1; j < byteMass.length && byteMass[i] == byteMass[j]; j++) {
```

This way, the inner loop breaks as soon as `byteMass[i] == byteMass[j]` evaluates to `false`. now let's restart our process with the new inner for loop

```
byteMass = 133333444478126354444
(byteMass.length = 21)
length = 0
    0 (i) < 21 (byteMass.length): true
        count = 0
        1 (j) < 21 && 1 (byteMass[0 (i)]) == 3 (byteMass[1 (j)]): false
    1 (i) < 21: true
        count = 0
        2 (j) < 21 && 3 (byteMass[1 (i)]) == 3 (byteMass[2 (j)]): true
            0 (count) >= 0 (length): true
                length = 1 (0 (count) + 1)
                element = 1 (i)
                lastElement = 2 (2 (j) - 0 (count))
            count = 1 (0 (count) + 1)
        3 (j) < 21 && 3 (byteMass[2 (1 (i) + 1 (count))]) == 3 (byteMass[3 (j)]): true
            1 (count) >= 1 (length): true
                length = 2 (1 (count) + 1)
                element = 1 (i)
                lastElement = 2 (3 (j) - 1 (count))
```

This seems like unexpected behavior to me, but I won't fix it because I don't know how: I have no idea what element and lastElement represent. The code continues on like this until j = 6:

```
        6 (j) < 21 && 3 (byteMass[5 (1 (i) + 4 (count))]) == 4 (bteMass[3 (j)]): false
    2 (i) < 21: true
        count = 0
        3 (j) < 21: true
            3 (byteMass[2 (2 (i) + 0 (count))]) == 3 (byteMass[3 (j)]): true
                length = 1 (0 (count) + 1)
                element = 2 (i)
                lastElement = 3 (3 (j) - 1 (count))
            count = 1 (0 (count) + 1)
```

This once again continues in the same fashion until j = 6. At this point hopefully you can see why your program isn't working as expected. But I still haven't answered the question of how to fix it. I don't really understand your thought process on how to solve this problem but I'll share with you my own

First of all we need to **break the problem into smaller chunks**!

You can do that any way you want to but here's my way: Our goal is to find the longest repeated pattern. Well in order to do that we need to figure out

1. when a number repeats itself and how many times it repeats itself
2. if that specific number repeated itself that specific amount of times anywhere else in the sequence. If it does, we'll need to save the amount of times it repeats itself
3. Then we'll repeat the process but only save the data if the number of repeats is larger than the saved data

It's actually a kind of complex problem and will probably be easier to solve with helper functions to be honest. I hope this helps!